# In android geolocation not working in emulator and also in mobiles

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-geolocation

In my application the location updates are not working and the app get closed when i click on start location updates button. I am a beginner i doesnt know how to debug this error.What i want from my application is

- the application must updates the location on every minutes
- the application will work on background and it will close when we close the applications like music player

**Main_activity.class**

```
package com.example.admin.locationapidemo;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import java.sql.Connection;
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener{

 - List item

private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 1000;

    private Location mLastLocation;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    private boolean mRequestLocationUpdates = false;

    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    private static int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 10000;
    private static int FATEST_INTERVAL = 5000;
    private static int DISPLACEMENT = 10;

    private TextView lblLocation;
    private Button btnShowLocation, btnStartLocationUpdates;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lblLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblLocation);
        btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonShowLocation);
        btnStartLocationUpdates = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLocationUpdates);

        if(checkPlayServices()) {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            createLocationRequest();
        }

        btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                displayLocation();
            }
        });

        btnStartLocationUpdates.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                togglePeriodLocationUpdates();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if(mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        checkPlayServices();
        if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && mRequestLocationUpdates) {
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        stopLocationUpdates();
    }

    private void displayLocation() {
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if(mLastLocation != null) {
            double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
            double longtitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();

            lblLocation.setText(latitude + ", " + longtitude);
        } else {
            lblLocation.setText("Couldn't get the location. Make sure location is enabled on the device");
        }
    }

    private void togglePeriodLocationUpdates() {
        if(!mRequestLocationUpdates) {
            btnStartLocationUpdates.setText(getString(R.string.btn_stop_location_updates));

            mRequestLocationUpdates = true;

            startLocationUpdates();
        } else {
            btnStartLocationUpdates.setText(getString(R.string.btn_start_location_updates));

            mRequestLocationUpdates = false;

            stopLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    }

    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FATEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT);
    }

    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if(resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if(GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This device is not supported", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

    protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        displayLocation();

        if(mRequestLocationUpdates) {
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLastLocation = location;

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location changed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        displayLocation();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }
}
```

**My xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@color/view_bg">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/lbl_you_are_at"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblLocation"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonShowLocation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="@color/btn_bg"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:text="@string/btn_get_location"
        android:textColor="@color/view_bg"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLocationUpdates"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:background="@color/btn_bg"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:text="@string/btn_start_location_updates"
        android:textColor="@color/view_bg"/>




</LinearLayout>
```

**Manifest file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.admin.locationapidemo">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"></service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Hi, can you share any exception or stack traces from logcat?

Comment: Is location service of mobile on?

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.example.admin.locationapidemo, PID: 3811
                                                                                 java.lang.SecurityException: Client must have ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to request PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY locations.

Comment: Yes i manually on the location services

Answer (score 0):

```
private void displayLocation() {
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if(mLastLocation != null) {
            double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
            double longtitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();

            lblLocation.setText(latitude + ", " + longtitude);
        } else {
            lblLocation.setText("Couldn't get the location. Make sure location is enabled on the device");
        }
    }
```

remove this line

```
mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
```

because in onLocationChanged() you are assigning value to mLastLocation, so try to use that assigned value.

Comment: I had tried this one also but also i had a same error

Comment: Did you get "Location changed!" toast on your screen ?

Comment: In some mobile this code will works fine but in emulator it doesnt  and also in some mobiles am having the same error

Comment: which emulator you are using ? if you are using android virtual device manager then follow these steps on the right side of your android emulator where (Power Button ,Speaker , Camera etc signs are given find three dot sign(...) at the last of that column. click on that then click on location and Set the Latitude and longitude and hit send button

Comment: please check the app info in your settings if location permission is enabled for your application or not, because same code is working in my emulator

Comment: yes its correct the location permission  is not enabled in a device

Comment: now its working fine may i know how to add a background services to this